# Reusing view in UIPickerView with iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

**EDIT 12-14-2015** : This problem is again frequently reported on iOS 7, iOS 8, iOS 9.... I think Apple want not of this control anymore, and should just forbid us to use it instead of let such a major bug

I use a UIPickerView with custom views loaded from a Xib. 
I was using the method

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row 
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

from UIPickerViewDelegate to reuse my views.

With iOS 6, my UIPickerview works perfectly and my views are reused.

Since iOS 7, the reusingView is always nil, so I need to load the NIB for each row (I have 250 rows). My views are doing some treatments so it can take a little part of memory but x250 = big memory leak.

To be sure of what the problem is, I did a simple project with a UILabel :

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
    if(view == nil) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 76)];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"*******************************************************");
    }
    NSLog(@"Current inndex : %i",row);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TITRE %i", row];
    return label;
}
```

With iOS 6, my views are correctly reused :

> 2013-12-17 14:27:25.395 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex
>   : 220 2013-12-17 14:27:25.396 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.397 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 221
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.404 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.407 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 222
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.409 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.410 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 223
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.411 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.412 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 224
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.414 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.415 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 225
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.420 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]
>   ******************************************************* 2013-12-17 14:27:25.424 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907] Current inndex : 227
>   2013-12-17 14:27:25.425 EssaiReusedViewPicker[261:907]

But with iOS 7, it's an all-new story... :

```
2013-12-17 14:36:09.555 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 0
2013-12-17 14:36:09.557 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:09.557 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:09.560 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 0
2013-12-17 14:36:09.560 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:09.561 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:09.563 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 0
2013-12-17 14:36:09.563 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:09.564 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:09.566 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 0
2013-12-17 14:36:09.567 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:09.567 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:09.568 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:09.568 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:09.569 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 0
2013-12-17 14:36:09.569 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 1
2013-12-17 14:36:14.172 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 3
2013-12-17 14:36:14.350 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 3
2013-12-17 14:36:14.351 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 2
2013-12-17 14:36:14.367 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 4
2013-12-17 14:36:14.667 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 4
2013-12-17 14:36:14.668 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 3
2013-12-17 14:36:14.700 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 5
2013-12-17 14:36:15.067 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 5
2013-12-17 14:36:15.067 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 4
2013-12-17 14:36:15.083 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 6
2013-12-17 14:36:15.367 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 6
2013-12-17 14:36:15.367 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 5
2013-12-17 14:36:15.400 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 7
2013-12-17 14:36:16.416 EssaiReusedViewPicker[7209:70b] Current inndex : 7
```

So what's wrong? iOS or ...?

Comment: "(I have 250 rows)", are you using a `UITableViewCell` with a `UIPickerview` subview?

Comment: No, a simple UIView. It shouldn't be a problem because it's possible to use the reused views with a UILabel. Even with a UILabel, it's not working

Comment: If you have rows, why don't you use `UITableView` with custom cells?

Comment: Because i don't want a tableView but a UIPickerView ... Because the UIPickerView is the appropriate component when i need to select an item in a list.

Comment: Oh, so you want to reuse the `UILabel`s you use in the `UIPickerView`

Comment: Yes. I really don't have UILabels in my pickerView but custom views (because i need it). But when i saw that my custom views weren't reused, in decided to try with simple UILabel in my PickerView. And i have the same probleme : even UILabel are not reused on iOS7 whereas they are on iOS 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have reported my problem to Apple Technical Support. They confirm the bug :

> There does indeed seem to be a difference between the behavior in iOS 6 and 7.

They ask me to report a bug on the bugreport tool. Now, just wait for the fix :)

Comment: This bug has been fixed with iOs 7.1

Comment: I don't agree that the bug was fixed. I see no sign that this bug is fixed in iOS 7 or iOS 7.1 — or iOS 8. I'm going to file the bug again.

Comment: Weird :/ 
When i add a breakpoint in "tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" that seems good for me.

Comment: Right @QLag but this is not `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It is not a table view at all. This is `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`.

Comment: Run my [downloadable example here](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p568pickerView/ch25p842pickerView/ViewController.swift) and you will see that no labels are being reused: in fact, as you scroll up and down we create hundreds and hundreds of labels, even though the picker view has only fifty rows.

Comment: Yeah sorry i did a mistake in my last comment. I wanted to mean "picker" and not "tableview" of course

Comment: Well, you can run my [example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p568pickerView/ch25p842pickerView/ViewController.swift) on 7, 7.1, or 8, and you will see that we never reuse any labels.

Comment: I believe you but i can't actually run swift code :/

Comment: Appears that the bug is still present in iOS 9. Have submitted a radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5546826446929920