# Why are the views never reused in UIPickerView for delegate viewForRow?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipickerview

I'm trying to implement a UIPickerView with a custom view. Oddly, the reused view is alway nil, when I scroll through the items in the picker view.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
           reusingView:(UIView *)view
{ 
    UILabel* label = (UILabel *)view;
    if (label==nil) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 22);
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        view = label;
    }
    else {            
        NSLog(@"This is never called");
    }
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using iOS7.0 its a bug see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21039321/790842

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. Looks like I need to implement my own view recycling code.