# losing data while UIPickerView reload in ios 7.1 simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I am having issue in the UIPickerView.I am trying to create the UIImageView's based on the below method

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

In the above method I put one condition .i.e `if(view == nil)` but it always return that the view is nil, it is not enter into else condition.

Code is

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
if(view == nil)
{
    UIView *rowView;
        rowView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 22)] retain];
        [rowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIImageView *checkOrUncheck = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 1, 18, 18)];
        [checkOrUncheck setImage:nil];
        [checkOrUncheck setTag:-100];

        UIButton *rowLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        rowLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 1, 904, 20);
        [rowLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [rowLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rowLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:22]];
        rowLabel.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [rowLabel setTag:-101];

        if([pickerView isEqual:returnDatePicker])
        {
            [rowLabel setTitle:[returnDatesDurationArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if([pickerView isEqual:selectProductPicker])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [selectProductsArray objectAtIndex:row];
            [rowLabel setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        [rowView addSubview:checkOrUncheck];
        [rowView addSubview:rowLabel];
    }
else
{
        NSLog(@"no");
}
    return rowView;
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong in my code. Thanks for spending time for my post.

Comment: This seems to be a confirmed bug in iOS 7. You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635949/reusing-view-in-uipickerview-with-ios-7