# UIPickerViewModel doesn't cache views

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I have an UIPickerView with an UIPickerViewModel. In the model I did overwritten the GetView method.

```
public class PickerViewDelegate : UIPickerViewModel {
...

public override UIView GetView (UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view) {

    var tv = (UITextView)view;

    if (view == null) {

        view = new UITextView(frame) {
            Font = ...
        };
        tv = view;
    }

    tv.Text = ...;

    return view;

}

}
```

The problem is that the view (the 3rd parameter of the GetView method) is always null and I must allocate a new UITextView. It is ok for 5 items, but I have about 200 items and it takes to long time.

Can you please give me a hint - what I missed, what I need to note to get the view cached?

Thank you.

Andrey Baboshin

Comment: may be related to this bug as described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635949/reusing-view-in-uipickerview-with-ios-7/21039321#21039321

Comment: Could you use a converter instead of overriding the GetView? Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: @PmanAce what do you mean with the converter?

Comment: @anders Thank you! You are right. I need just improve my google skills.