# UIPickerView Not Reusing Previous Component View

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I need to change the font of a UIPickerView and am using the delegate method as shown below.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = view as? UILabel;

    if (pickerLabel == nil)
    {
        pickerLabel = UILabel()

        pickerLabel?.font = UIFont(name: (pickerLabel?.font.fontName)!, size: 15)
        pickerLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }

    pickerLabel?.text = myData[row]

    return pickerLabel!
}
```

As I understand the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614389-pickerview), once I have created the UILabel views, they should get reused. However, the "view" parameter is always nil. Every time I spin the picker, it creates a new UILabel. This seems inefficient and defeats the object of having the "reusing" parameter.

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood how it ought to work?

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Is the `view` itself nil when the function is called? Or is the result of the `var pickerLabel = view as? UILabel` giving you a nil value for the `pickerLabel`?

Comment: The 'view' itself is always nil every time the function is called, regardless of whether the picker is being set up initially, or spun once set up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an iOS System bug. And it's not been fixed even on iOS 10.2. Check the related issue: [Reusing view in UIPickerView with iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635949/reusing-view-in-uipickerview-with-ios-7/21039321#21039321)